# FOSRestBundle / JMSSerializerBundle: interact with Symfony2 Security roles

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I want to serialize and return only a few attributes of my entity with JMSSerializerBundle and FOSRestBundle.

For example I have this attributes:

**User**

- Username
- E-Mail
- Birthday
- Comments

**Comments**

- Text
- DateTime

Users with the role ROLE_ADMIN should get a serialized object of the whole user-object. ROLE_USER should only get the username and all comments.

What's the easiest way to implement the Symfony2 Security Component in JMSSerializerBundle? Or do I need to implement this in my controller and serialize it "by hand"?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have to do it all by hand. It sounds like serialization groups might be a good solution here.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/** @Groups({"admin", "user"}) */
$username

/** @Groups({"admin"}) */
$email

/** @Groups({"admin"}) */
$birthday

/** @Groups({"admin", "user"}) */
$comments
```

In your controller, it would just be a matter of checking the role and using the correct serialization group.

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
$serializer->setGroups(array("admin")); or $serializer->setGroups(array("admin","user"));
```

Another option would be the [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/1.0) which lets you secure methods on your controller by role. Provide a different route/method for each option and let the bundle handle access control.